# Search Multiple Sources for Data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, algorithm, hashmap

I am building a search for cars. I want to search through multiple apis/databases and output the top ten cars that match my input values - make, model, year, color ...
My search model looks like this

```
##search.rb  my model## 

def candidates  
  @cars ||= get_cars
end

def car_databsae_one
   client = ...
end

def car_databsae_two
   client = ...
end

def car_databsae_three
   client = ...
end

def car_databsae_four
   client = ...
end

def car_databsae_five
   client = ...
end

private

def search_car_database_one
    ... returns results that match request to db1
end

def search_car_database_two
    ... returns results that match request db2 +
   if a car is both one and two merge the information 
end

def search_car_database_three
     ... returns results that match request db3 +
   if a car is one, two, and three merge the information
   or one and three
   or two and three
end  

def search_car_database_four
    ...
end

def search_car_database_five
    ...
end

def get_cars
  all_cars = search_car_database_five
end
```

Is there a better way to search all apis at once and pull the data. The catch is every time a car is seen in multiple databases the data will be added to that car's hash.

Comment: "database" isn't spelled "databsae". You should fix that for consistency otherwise you'll likely encounter bugs or maintenance problems.

Comment: I will make that correction. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So, each "database" is actually an API? And, where and how are those APIs defined?

I think a wiser solution would not explicitly define all of this. I think you'd be wiser to pull those "databases" into a list (Array), and have a method to iterate over those. From there, preventing duplication in results is up to you and your code.

Comment: Yes the databases are Apis